# Vue js fetch JSON before it renders

Tags: json, vue.js, lifecycle

I have a question regarding get JSON data object and render it before it mounted.
just in case, I'm developing standalone.
I don't think the function has problem. I think it's on the life cycling side.
so I have empty array variable called `listData:[]` on the VueJS data instance and `this.listData.push(response.body)` to push objects into it. on the HTML side, I v-for the elements to render elements.
It shows the result well but on the console, I see error message that `'undefined'` it cannot find data in array to loop over. 
of course it's empty array when it's render it for the first time.
I don't want to see this error. sometime, it does not render correctly.. 
so is there any solution to it?
If you need additional information. I would like to add more. Thank you.

### JSON

```
{
  section1_header: 'A',
  section2_header: 'B',
  section3: {
   0:{
     subtitle: 'C',
     title: '4' 
     },
   1:{
     subtitle: 'D',
     title: '%' 
     },
  }
}
```

### HTML

```
<div class="s3-subcontainer" v-for="(item, index) in listData[0].section3">
      <ul class="s3-script">
        <li class="s3-subtitle" v-html="item.subtitle"></li>
        <li class="s3-title" v-html="item.title"></li>
      <ul>  
 </div>
```

### JS

```
 fetchJson: function () {
   this.$http.get('')
     .then(response => {
        this.listData.push(response.body);
         console.log('list', this.listData);
   })
 }
```

### error

[image: console error]

Comment: If your `listData` is an empty array initially, `v-for` will not iterate it and you should not get any errors. Without showing your template code and the actual error message, this question cannot be answered

Comment: @Phil yes you are right, sorry for my explanation. I edited my post, I can't post the whole JSON objects but I'm trying to iterate nested object.

Comment: Your _"JSON"_ is not JSON. Well, not valid JSON in any case

Comment: @Phil oops.. I don't know why I put array there.. it suppose to be object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your *"JSON"* is actually an object and not an array, I don't see why you'd want `listData` to be an array at all.

Because your `v-for` expression is `listData[0].section3`, you should set the initial value to something that will not cause errors. For example (and making it just an object)...

```js
data () { // assuming this is a component
  return {
    listData: {
      section3: []
    }
  }
}
```

and use

```
<div class="s3-subcontainer" v-for="(item, index) in listData.section3">
```

I would also simply set the `listData` value instead of trying to push it.

```
.then(response => { this.listData = response.body })
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Phil. I don't need to push it.. and I assigned initial value to the `listData` i don't see error anymore!